# Android interactive UI

Tags: android, interactive

How can I have an interactive help in my android software. I want to force user to do what I'm telling to him, touch that point I'm telling to him.

I want to help users how to work with software as I'm showing the ability to them.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you already have some code?

Comment: @GhostDerfel unfortunately no; I'm just started to get familiar with these kind of programming. a bit help can help me a lot;

Comment: I used fragments at top of actual content to show help. These fragments correspond UI of content (fragments) below. Also, check this library https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView it's similar what Android uses.

Comment: @Michal thanks for the link to ShowcaseView. Discovered that some time ago, and was looking for it now, but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

What I can recomend you to do is to set your view to be in a RelativeLayout with an layer to "catch" the touch and force the user to click only where you want.
Just a simple example that can get better if you add some animation's and some code review.

This will be your root layout:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/tutorial_layer"
    style="@style/HomeTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</View>

<include layout="@layout/my_layout" />
```

Then you can implement something like that on your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    RelativeLayout tutorialLayer;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       tutorialLayer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tutorial_layer);
       button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);//Let's suppose this button exist on your layout
       tutorialLayer.setOnTouchListener(this);
       if(needToSeeTutorial())
         tutorialLayer.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
    }    

    private boolean needToSeeTutorial(){
     //Add your logic here :D
     return false;
    }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      int x = event.getX();
      int y = event.getY();

      if(x >= button.getX() && x <= (button.getX()+button.getWidth() && y >= button.getY() && y <= (button.getY()+button.getHeight()){
        //Do what you need to do here
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click on the button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      }

   }

}
```

I just type the code directly here, so maybe this have some problem, also I'm not sure the logic to get x and y is right, but you can have an idea of the solution